# how do you find the length of a curve defined by two points of a function?

Tags: calculus, geometry

how do you find the length of a curve defined by two points of a function?

for an example x^2 between 0 and 1

[image]

what is the length of this curve and how would you find it for any function f(x) between x=a and x=b

[image]

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arc_length#:~:text=Arc%20length%20is%20the%20distance,called%20rectification%20of%20a%20curve.

Comment: It is simply $\;\displaystyle\int_a^b\sqrt{1+f'^2(x)}\,\mathrm dx$.

Comment: @Bernard does this work for *any* function?

Comment: For any differentiable fu,ction, that's the formula I learnt when I was a student. There exists a similar formula for parameterised curves.

Comment: @Bernard thanks, just realized this is on the wiki page...

Answer (score 0):

When we "zoom" in on a smooth, continuous function, the curve it creates begins to look like a straight line. By splitting the curve into smaller and smaller straight line elements $\,ds$, then the total arc length will be the sum of all of the infinitesimal arc length elements. We parameterize the curve with a variable, $t$. We can then form a right triangle with hypotenuse $\frac{\,ds}{\,dt}$ and legs $\frac{\,dx}{\,dt}$, $\frac{\,dy}{\,dt}$ being the horizontal and vertical legs respectively for any arc length element. By using the Pythagorean theorem, we see that $\,ds=\sqrt{\left(\frac{\,dx}{\,dt}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\,dy}{\,dt}\right)^2}\,dt$.

Then the arc length  $L=\displaystyle\int \,ds=\displaystyle\int_{t_1}^{t_2}\sqrt{\left(\frac{\,dx}{\,dt}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\,dy}{\,dt}\right)^2}\,dt$.

By 'factoring' out $\left(\frac{\,dx}{\,dt}\right)^2$, we can obtain $L=\displaystyle\int \,ds=\displaystyle\int_{a}^{b}\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{\,dy}{\,dx}\right)^2}\,dx$.